# How to read an array of floats from .dat file in Python?

Tags: python, dat-protocol

I have .dat file with this type of text

**Example:**
АqMA          ЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB     MA         @ЅA        Е€ї  HB  HB    ЂXLA         ЂЅA        U­‡ї  HB  HB    АFA        U5ЅA        Е€ї  HB  HB    @ю@A          ЅA         ё€ї  HB  HB     [VA          ЅA        ±“‡ї  HB  HB    @3MA          ЅA        U=‰ї  HB  HB    А KA        «JЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    ЂdJA        ;1ЅA         р‡ї  HB  HB     АZA        «jЅA         `†ї  HB  HB    АFA        ±ЅA        Uе†ї  HB  HB    А¬XA          ЅA        bЗ€ї  HB  HB    АHA        OlЅA        «2€ї  HB  HB    А5WA        UЅA        vB‰ї  HB  HB    АN>A          ЅA        Uu€ї  HB  HB     >FA        UuЅA        Ы†ї  HB  HB    А^A        ±ЅA        «2€ї  HB  HB    А”\A        UuЅA        OL€ї  HB  HB    ЂГOA        OlЅA         р‡ї  HB  HB    @аEA        UЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    @QHA        OlЅA         р‡ї  HB  HB    АeOA          ЅA        vB‰ї  HB  HB     цQA        ЕNЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    @QHA         ЂЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB     ,IA         ЂЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    @эUA        «*ЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB     DEA        ЕNЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    ЂҐTA         ЂЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    АоMA         ЂЅA        «ъ€ї  HB  HB    @   TA         ЂЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    А0CA         ЂЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    @KIA         ЂЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    ЂXA         ЂЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    АYQA        «jЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    @жDA        ;1ЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB     IYA         ЂЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    @oCA         ЂЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    ЂFOA         ЂЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB     ТWA        Щ  ЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB     OA        UuЅA         Ђ‰ї  HB  HB    @WGA **etc...**

It should be matrix (..., 10) with correct float numbers, but idk how to do it. I tried to find what kind of record it is, but i couldn't find anything same :(

Pls help

ps

in matlab it magicaly works fine, but i really can't do the same in Python

```
FileID = fopen('sample.dat' ,'r');
Data = fread(FileID,[10,inf],'float')';
```

[image: Data in matlab pic]

Comment: it's just data, and interpreting it as text will be fairly meaningless.. you should look into python's [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library in order to unpack raw binary data into data, as well as [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html), and [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)

Comment: Your picture doesn't open.

Comment: @Aaron , It shows up now, it was due to a DNS misconfiguration.

Comment: How was the .dat file created? If it was created with matlab (using  dat instead on .mat), you could use `from scipy.io import loadmat; 
data = loadmat('sample.dat')`

Comment: @np8 the [matlab example shows how the file can be interpreted](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html)... it's just packed binary floats reshaped into 10 columns by however many rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is simply a bunch of floats represented by their actual binary data rather than text. [Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) is probably the fastest and easiest by using:

`numpy.fromfile(filepath, dtype=float).reshape([-1,10])`

It may be a good exercise to learn how binary data is represented by using the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library. Here's a quick example to try and read through:

```
with open(filepath, 'rb') as datafile:
    my_array = list()
    for i, value in enumerate(struct.iter_unpack('f', datafile)):
        if i%10 == 0: #start a new row every 10 columns
            my_array.append(list())
        my_array[-1].append(value)
```

Comment: Thank u, it worked for me to do something similar to, but still very far away, because numbers are not the same as they should be. I'll try to use this struct library like you said)

Comment: try playing around with data type, byte endianness, and starting offset. There should be no difference. Also look and make sure the data isn't just transposed... iirc matlab is column first, and numpy is row first

Comment: import numpy as np
data = np.fromfile('sample3.dat', dtype = 'float32').reshape([-1,10])